# Referencing multi-dimensional arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, reference

```
int a[3][2] = {{3, 6}, {8, 4}, {7, 1}}; 
cout << *a[1] << *(*a + 1);
```

This is my first question here, so please excuse me if I break any rules.

How does the code work? It would be great if someone explained how referencing in multi-dimensional arrays work.

The output to the code is 86.

Comment: You're going to have to explain what you think it does, and where your knowledge gaps are.

Comment: Note: `*(x + y)` is often better written as `x[y]`. `*x` is also largely equivalent to `x[0]`, as it's effectively `*(x + 0)`.

Comment: I understand what you've said in your note for single-dimension array. What I don't get is, what does it mean here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember pointers and arrays are easily intermingled in C++ as that's something it inherits from C. As such `a[n]` and `*(a + n)` are effectively the same, just two different ways of expressing the same thing, though arguably the `a[n]` notation is much simpler and should be used for clarity.

The 2D version is `a[n][m]` which expands to `*(a + n)[m]` or going one further, `*(*(a + n) + m)`.

If `m` is `0`, then you get `*(*(a + n))`.

So for `n=1` `m=0` then `*(*(a + 1))`.

Answer (score 1):

`a[1]` is referencing second element in array `a` (in this case it is `{8, 4}`), `*` in front of it accesses the first element of `{8, 4}` (`8`).

`(*a + 1)` means the first value of a plus one. In this case it is pointer to start of array `{3, 6}` plus one, which means *pointer to the second element of `{3, 6}`*. Adding `*` to the statement I've explained means *value, pointed by this pointer*.

If this is written to teach you how the pointers work, it's ok, but in your code is better to use something like `a[1][2]`.

I'm not sure if I've explained clearly or not, please tell me if you did not understand.